# transferring files from remote host to local machine

Tags: ssh

I used `ssh -X <ip_addresss_of_remote_host>` to connect to a remote host from my local computer. I am using ubuntu 12.04. Now that I can browse internet on the remote host by opening firefox using "firefox" command in the terminal. Now any file I download from the internet goes to the remote host. Is there anyway I can setup the connection such that a file downloaded comes directly to my local computer??

Comment: Yes. Open Firefox locally.

Comment: I tried that! Actually my local computer is not connected to internet, rather it is connected to an intranet. I am not getting internet access when I open firefox locally. That is the reason why I am using this remote connection, to browse the internet.

Comment: I will insist on opening Firefox locally because it's the "cleaner" solution in so many ways. You could try tunneling the relative ports over ssh (22) so that they become available to your local computer. Please see if [this](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Using_SSH_to_Port_Forward) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount your local directory on the remote server. That way, even though the file would be downloaded on the remote server, it would actually be stored on your local computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a browser on a remote host for some good reason. Therefore, the get those files to your local computer, put the downloaded files somewhere in your user path, then FTP to the remote host and download the files to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to set the download directory in your remote firefox session to a shared directory that you have access to on your local machine as well.

However, if I were you, I'd just copy the downloaded files to your local machine using `rsync`:

```
rsync -az <remote_host>:/path/to/firefox/download/dir ./dir
```